# Differences between @AccessTimeout(value = 0) and @Lock(LockType.WRITE)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timeout, ejb, concurrentmodification

As I read in *Beggining With Java 7 EE*:

> @Lock(LockType.WRITE): A method associated with an exclusive lock will
> not allow  concurrent invocations until the method’s processing is
> completed.
>
> An @AccessTimeoutvalue of 0 indicates that concurrent access is not
> allowed. This will result in throwing a ConcurrentAccessExceptionif a
> client invokes a method that is currently being used.

So... what's the difference? Both annotation disables concurrent invocations and I don't see any difference beetwen them. Is there any situation when it makes sense to use them together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method will block subsequent callers until the current one finish its call. The second, `@AccessTimeoutvalue` will throw an exception if there are more than one calls at the same time. Quite a difference.

Comment: I've spent too much time today reading this book and I stopped to think, thanks.

Comment: You'll learn much better if you run some code, play with it and debug. A good start could be the Quickstart Wildfly Project (https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart)

Comment: Thanks, first I wanted to read whole chapter about EJB and understand everything before I start coding, but it turns out that there was nothing to understand. It was only my oversight. : )

Comment: Most of the time textbooks describe something that is quite obvious from the code itself